# How to call didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, background, notifications, uilocalnotification

I need background process (for to call a webservice) to call didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification once app launch state, How to do that, please help me.

Thanks in Advance

I tried this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif
{
    if (app.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive )
    {
        NSLog(@"app not running");
    }
    else if(app.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive )
    {
        NSLog(@"app running");
    }
}
```

Comment: You just want the method to be called or you want to create a notification which calls the method?

Comment: create notification, once app launched state to call didReceiveLocalNotification

Answer (score 1):

This is how I create a local notification which is scheduled at 17:00 on the day this code runs. Once it fires, the method `-(void)application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` will be called.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[dateComponents setHour:17];
[dateComponents setMinute:00];
[dateComponents setSecond:00];

NSDate *notificationDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];

UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotif.fireDate = notificationDate;
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

localNotif.alertBody = @"blah blah blah";
localNotif.alertAction = @"Ok";

localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

Answer (score 0):

Notification is recieved in 2 cases

1. In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, if the app is
   neither running nor in the background.
2. In `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` method if the app is
   either running or in background. Its almost useless to show the
   alert when the app is already running. So you have to show the alert
   only when the app was in background at the time the notification
   fired. To know if the app is resuming from background use the
   `applicationWillEnterForeground:` method.

l

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
            UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];  
            if (localNotif) {       
                // Show Alert Here
            }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be true anymore. didReceiveLocalNotification is only called if you app is in the foreground. NOT if it is the background and the user taps on the alert.

Comment: "Its almost useless to show the alert when the app is already running".... you sure about that? So lets say you make a Twitter app and someone mentions @you, wouldn't you like to see some kind of banner or popup or something to let you know about the tweet when using the app?